# Error ¿PATH? NODE NPM! instala pero no lo encuentra al ejecutar

Tags: angularjs, npm, nodejs

Hola tengo un gran problema en mac osX

Tengo instalado node 6.5.0; npm 3.10.3

y al instalar cualquier dependencia como por ejemplo bower lo instala en una carpeta oculta en mi escritorio:

[image: Node y npm version + ruta en donde se instalan las aplicaciones!]

el problema en el caso de bower es que al querer ejecutarlo no lo reconoce.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ya re instale 2 veces node borrando sus directorios pero aún persiste este impasse

otro ejemplo:

sudo npm -g install -g yo:

[image: instalando yo]

y al ejecutar vuelve a mostrar command not found!:

[image: error]

¿Como lo soluciono? ¿sera el path?, por favor.

Answer (score 1):

Revisa si la carpeta donde instalar nod tiene permisos de administrador, normalmente node.js se instala en la carpeta `/usr/local/bin/node`. Y también asegúrate que dentro de agregar en tu `$PATH` esta dirección `/usr/local/bin`.

Answer (score 0):

Cambia el prefijo que npm usa para instalar *packages* para que estén en `/usr/local/lib/node_modules` (como normalmente lo hacen) y no en `/Users/Usuario/.npm-packages`.

Para cambiarlo puedes usar: `npm config set prefix /usr/local`

Comment: con ese comando yo le indico que me instale los packages en esa ruta verdad?  pero al cerrar la terminal se desacera el cambio y para que eso no suceda tengo que editar el path de profile creo pero como lo hago?

Comment: si con ahí tu le indicas que quieres que los instale en `/usr/local/lib/node_modules` y eso se queda guardado aunque cierres la terminal. Si quieres verlo usa `npm get prefix` para que te muestre valor que tiene. Y en el PATH si tiene que estar `/usr/local/lib/node_modules`